# self signed SSL Certificates & nginx issues

Tags: ssl, certificate, self, signed

say,I've a domain abc.com,I've made a self signed SSL Certificate successfully for www.abc.com,(even *.abc.com),however it doesn't work for abc.com

how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards in `*.abc.com` don't work for `abc.com` as there is a significant dot. Try to use multiple DNS entries in your subject alternative name extension instead (in fact, that's the recommended way anyway, it's even preferable to wildcards in most cases).

Comment: But those Commercial SSL Certificates support both,I don't know how.

Comment: Do you have an example commercial certificate for which browser would treat `example.com` as valid for `*.example.com`?

Comment: Dear xxx.com,

Thank you for placing your order. We are pleased to announce that your PositiveSSL Certificate for xxx.com has been issued.

To help reduce domain name mismatch warnings, we have also included the domain name www.xxx.com in your certificate.

Comment: I guess they do it with multiple S.A.N. entries. (Some have multiple CN components in the Subject DN, but different browsers may interpret that differently.)